# How to hide a box selection visual element around menu items?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hide

Sometimes (not always) when I click a menu element on my webpage's header an annoying selection box appears (see the picture). Can I hide it somehow? Why is it there at all?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMTGO.jpg

Comment: just set a:focus, a:visited, a:hover {outline: none}

Comment: This is not outline exactly. It is for Accessibilty line for the visually challanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `outline:none` to anchor tag class

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing -- 
`a:visited, a:hover, a:focus {outline: none}`